# Unix: Spliting pipe delimited String containing consecutive spaces

Tags: string, shell, parsing, unix, ksh

I have a problem splitting a pipe delimited line containing consecutive spaces using a Unix-Script.

Let’s say I have a file with lines like

```
Filename.txt|instancename1|PARAMETER1='C  15 K','G 7H 35'|PARAMETER2=56||PARAMETER3=TEST||instancename2|PARAMETER1='C  15 K','G 7H 35'||
...
...
```

So far my Unix-Script looks like this (unnecessary parts striped):

```
#!/bin/ksh

WORKDIR=$1

FILE_WORK_DIR=somedir/$WORKDIR
PARAM_FILE=$FILE_WORK_DIR/TESTFILE.csv

while read PARAM_LINE
do
  OUT_FNAME=`echo $PARAM_LINE |cut -d'|' -f1`
  echo $PARAM_LINE |awk -F'|' '{n=split($0,col,FS);
                                for (i=2;i<=n;i++) {if (col[i] != "") print col[i]}
                               }' > $FILE_WORK_DIR/$OUT_FNAME
done < $PARAM_FILE
```

The **desired** output should look like this:

```
instancename1
PARAMETER1='C  15 K','G 7H 35'
PARAMETER2=56
PARAMETER3=TEST
instancename2
PARAMETER1='C  15 K','G 7H 35'
```

Using this script my output looks like this:

```
instancename1
PARAMETER1='C 15 K','G 7H 35'
PARAMETER2=56
PARAMETER3=TEST
instancename2
PARAMETER1='C 15 K','G 7H 35'
```

If you look at PARAMETER1 the consecutive spaces getting trimmed to one space:

```
PARAMETER1='**C  15 K**','G 7H 35'
PARAMETER1='**C 15 K**','G 7H 35'
```

Why is that? I need consecutive spaces just as they are.
I guess it’s some super lame problem but my Unix skills aren’t that good.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Say `echo "$PARAM_LINE"` instead of `echo $PARAM_LINE`.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it without using awk

```
while IFS='|' read -A line; do
    >${line[0]}
    for item in "${line[1..-1]}"; do
            [[ -z $item ]] && continue
            echo "$item" >> ${line[0]}
    done
done < $PARAM_FILE
```